# Lebesgue measure of the set $\{t\in[0,T],W_t\geqslant a\}$

Tags: lebesgue-measure, brownian-motion

Let $(W_t)_{t\geqslant 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion, I am interested in the set $A:=\{ t\in[0,T],W_t\geqslant a\}$ where $T>0$ and $a>0$. In particular I want to evaluate the Lebesgue measure of this set, actually I don't know if the law of $\mu(A)$ or $\mathbb{E}[\mu(A)]$ are well known. I think the first Lévy's arcsine law (saying that $\mu(A)$ follows an arcsine distribution when $a=0$) might be useful but I have no clue how I could use it.

Comment: The expectation is easy enough. $\mathbb{E}[\mu(A)] = \mathbb{E}\int_0^T1_{\{W_t \geq a\}}dt = \int_0^T \mathbb{P}(W_t \geq a)dt = \int_0^T \int_a^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}dxdt$. I'm not sure about the law of the Lebesgue measure of the set off-hand though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there a nice way to compute this integral, or some good approximations ?

Comment: I don't think the integral has an explicit representation in terms of elementary functions. Approximations are definitely possible, but probably the right way of doing the approximation depends on the relative sizes of $a$ and $T$. Is there a particular regime you are interested in?

Comment: I am intersted in the case where $a$ is small. For the sake of simplicity let's suppose that $T=1$, then I find that
$$ \mathbb{E}[\mu(A)]=\frac{1}{2}(a^2+1){\rm erfc}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\frac{a}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}} ​$$
As for the law of $\mu(A)$, I still can't figure it out.

Comment: If you are happy with special functions, then you should be able to find the general form for any $T$ in terms of the error function by the same method. For the law, you can compute the integer moments of the random variable with the same trick: $\mathbb{E}[\mu(A)^2] = \mathbb{E}[\int_0^T 1_{\{W_t \geq a\}} dt \int_0^T 1_{W_s \geq a} ds] = \int_0^T\int_0^T \mathbb{P}(W_t \geq a, W_s \geq a)dsdt$ and similarly for higher moments. If you want a functional law in terms of Brownian motion, you could look at the proof of the Arcsin law via simple random walk and see if it generalizes. It might.

Comment: I'll see if I can find a proof of the arcsin law that can be generalized. However I had an idea for the proof and I would like to know if it works. Let $\tau:=\inf\{t>0,W_t=a\}$, it is known that $\tau<+\infty$ a.s. and that $\tau$ has the density $f_a(u):=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2\pi u^3}}e^{-\frac{a^2}{2u}}1_{\{u\geqslant 0\}}$, therefore for $\ell\in[0,1]$,
$$ \mathbb{P}(\mu(A)\leqslant\ell)=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathbb{P}(\mu(A)\leqslant\ell|\tau=s)f_a(s)ds $$

Comment: If $\tau\geqslant 1-\ell$, then $\mu(A)\leqslant\ell$ thus $\mathbb{P}(\mu(A)\leqslant\ell|\tau=s)=1$ when $s\geqslant 1-\ell$. If $\tau=s\leqslant 1-\ell$, then $B_t^s:=\frac{W_{s+(1-s)t}-a}{\sqrt{1-s}}$ is a standard Brownian bridge on $[0,1]$, we can therefore use the arcsin law and, letting $u=\frac{t-s}{1-s}$,
$$ \mu(A)=\int_s^1 1_{\{W_t\geqslant a\}}dt=(1-s)\int_0^1 1_{\{ B_u^s\geqslant 0 \}}du=(1-s)\mu(\{u\in[0,1],B_u^s\geqslant 0\}) $$

Comment: so that
$$ \mathbb{P}(\mu(A)\leqslant\ell)=\mathbb{P}\left(\mu(\{t\in[0,1],B_t^s\geqslant 0\})\leqslant\frac{\ell}{1-s}\right)=\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{\ell}{1-s}}\right) $$
because $\frac{\ell}{1-s}\leqslant 1$. We can then conclude :
$$\mathbb{P}(\mu(A)\leqslant\ell)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{1-\ell}\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{\ell}{1-s}}\right)f_a(s)ds+\int_{1-\ell}^{+\infty}f_a(s)ds $$
If there is no mistake, I'll put it as an answer.